# Double scale for CSV data in gnuplot

Tags: csv, plot, gnuplot

I would like to plot CSV data, and refer them with two x-axes. On the bottom  linear (4*$1^2) scale, and on the top - logarithmic scale in other units ($1). Both scales should refer to the same plot.

```
plot "sum_no_realloc.csv" using ($1*$1*4):4 with lines,
```

So the bottom scale should be in 4*$1^2 units, and the top should be in $1 units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the link command.

Suppose that your data file looks like this:

```
3 1
4 2
10 3
20 4
```

and you want to plot as you described.  The x2 axis needs to show the x-coordinates and the x1 axis needs to show the transformed coordinates.

Issue the following commands:

```
set link x2 via sqrt(x/4.0) inverse 4.0*x*x
set x2tics
```

Then if you plot by

```
plot "datafile.txt" using ($1*$1*4.0):2 with lines
```

You will see that the x2 axis runs from 0 to 20 and the x1 axis runs from 0 to 1600 (4*20*20).  The link command forces the two axes to be linked based on a mapping function.  You need to specify how the x2 axis is determined from the x1 axis and how to go the other way around as well - gnuplot will usually throw a warning message when you do this about not being able to confirm the mapping.

The following plot shows the results (I labeled the axes using the normal set xlab and set x2lab commands).

[image: Log and linear scale]

Comment: set link is not available on 4.6 version of gnuplot-x11, so I had to purge it, make and install the newest package 5.0. Now it works very well. Thank you.